# What equation can produce these curves?

Tags: curves

Does an equation exist that can produce the curves shown in the attached image, by varying a single variable?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean in principle, or are you asking for specific examples?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the equilateral hyperbola $xy=1$ and map the points $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ to two symmetrical points on the hyperbola $(t,t^{-1})$ and $(t^{-1},t)$ by translation/scaling (as if you were zooming in).

$$(x(t-t^{-1})+t^{-1})(y(t-t^{-1})+t^{-1})=1.$$

[image]

The straight line corresponds to two infinitely close points, $t=t^{-1}=1$, which is a degenerate case of the equation.

---

**Previous answer**:

You can think of a pencil of parabolas, $y=\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac\lambda{\sqrt2}(2x^2-1)$, which you rotate by $45°$ right, giving

$$x+y=1+\lambda\left((x-y)^2-1\right).$$

You can solve the quadratic equation for $y$.

Comment: If I take $(x,y)$ to be $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$, it seems to me that your equation is not satisfied.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: right, I forgot a $\sqrt2$ factor. Now fixed (hopefully).

Comment: This has become promising, since the it goes through the two points as required, and is has the symmetry that swapping $x$ and $y$ leaves the equation unchanged. However for some values of $\lambda$ it may look different than expected. Like when $\lambda$ is close to $1$, the vertex of the parabola is close to the origin, and the parabola (after rotation) crosses the coordinate axes in the "opposite" direction, I think.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: the exponent $2$ can be lessened, but at some point we are lacking curve specifications.

Comment: At what value of $\lambda$ will the two axes be __tangents__ at the two "fixed" points?

Comment: Your current image "before rotation" is also magnified by a factor $\sqrt{2}$ compared to the image of the question. The biggest isosceles right triangle has side lengths $1,1,\sqrt{2}$ in the correct solution, and side lengths $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2},2$ in the current image of this answer. One can easily confuse oneself with this. However, your formula $$x+y=1+\lambda\left((x-y)^2-1\right)$$ is good, as I said, because it is symmetric in swapping $x$ and $y$ and is correct for $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. It might still be interesting to see another family of curves, maybe hyperbolas instead of parabolas.

Comment: The plot does not correspond to the equation, I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming what you drew to be a parabola, and $p$ a constant to push each parabola along the line of symmetry,

$$ y = p (1-x^2) $$

Now rotate them clockwise by $\pi/4 \, , (x,y) \rightarrow ( x+y, x-y)/\sqrt2. $

EDIT1:

As you left it free as regards shape within constraints, we could use a cosh curve, sec curve etc.

In fact, we can *generalize* this using *any open even function E(x)* , passing through $(\pm 1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2} ). $

Letting

$$y(x,p) =  (1 + p *(1/2 - x^2) E(x)) /\sqrt{2} \,  $$

and building a differentiable function, rotating the curve by $-\pi/4$, we can  make the family pass through singular points $(0,1),(1,0) $as shown above and illustrated below in a particular case.

In  graph below $E(x) = \cos^2(x) $is chosen with $ p= (\pm 2,0). $
[image: Set of such Curves]

For the earlier special case you got parabolas using $E(x)=1 $ perturbed by arbitrary $p$ values.

Answer (score 2):

Try a [superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse): $|x|^a + |y|^a =1$ with $0 <a \le 1$.

Comment: Yes, but that curve will not intersect (pass through) the coordinate axes and continue into the 2nd/4th quadrant as shown in the image. But maybe that was not a requirement.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You could try analytic continuation, or simply remove the $|\cdot|$

Comment: @TobiasKienzler The superellipse with $a<1$ has a [_cusp_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)) at the point in question. It is not meeting the axis at a non-zero angle like in the drawing of the question.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Right you are, I spoke to soon...

Answer (score 2):

Try also a quadratic Bézier curve
$$
\gamma(t) = (1 - t)^{2} P_0 + 2(1 - t)t P_1 + t^{2} P_2 
$$
where $P_0=(1,0), P_1=(a,a), P_2=(0,1)$, with $a \in [0,0.5]$.

Answer (score 2):

You can first of all use a tool such as [Engauge Digitizer](https://markummitchell.github.io/engauge-digitizer/) to obtain tables of data points for each curve. Then either try a [Log-log plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot) to determine a polynomial approximation or use a fitting tool of your choice to obtain fits of the *same kind* for each curve. Finally, find a parameter describing each curve such that all the fit-parameters previously obtained can also be fitted by simple functions, ideally linear or a low-order polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Use Lagrange Interpolation formula: For a variable point $(t,t)$ on the line $x-y=0$ with $0<t\leq \sqrt2/2$, fit a degree 2 polynomial curve that passes through the three points $(0,1), (t,t)$ and $ (1,0)$.

For $t=\sqrt2/2$ the three points will be collinear and it will automatically give a straight line. 
This must produce  the same result  as Yves Daoust's answer above, but using different interpretation.